# Click event on one element to trigger click on element with attribute selector not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to make a script that allows me to click on one div and that click triggers click on another. This another element is outside and nowhere near this first element.

Element im clicking on:

```
<div id="one">
</div>
```

Clicking on that element i want to trigger click on this element:

```
<div class="swiper-slide" style="width: 356.6px;" data-slide-number="1" data-swiper-slide-index="1"></div>
```

There are multiple elements, only unique identifier is custom attribute so im using attribute selector to target it.

Here is jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '#one', function(event) { 
    $('[data-slide-number="1"]').click();
});
```

Its not working at all like this and i have no idea why.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] of the issue.  Going just off of the small snippets, there is nothing syntatically wrong with what you have.

Comment: which plugin are you using?

Comment: please provide minimal reproducible example so people can help you rather than we imagining things and then trying to solve the issue.